# How to fix this MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb

I am new to backend development. I took a project from GitHub and tried to run it, but when I am doing node index.js I am facing this error MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.How can i fix it? I tried to do mongodb://localhost:27017/server in DB_CREDENTIAL but the error is not fixed yet. Can anyone tell me how to fix that? How to fix this error in my case?

Code of db connect file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
async function initializeDBConnection(){
    
const mySecret = process.env['DB_CREDENTIAL']
 
    try{
        const uri = `mongodb+srv://${mySecret}@cluster0.iha7u.mongodb.net/social-media?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
 
        await mongoose.connect(uri, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        console.log("Connection Completed!");
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
 
module.exports = { initializeDBConnection };
```

Comment: `DB_CREDENTIAL` should contain `username:password` with this format

Comment: @lpizzinidev How to check that? i think mongodb://localhost:27017/name is that only i tried to do what you said but same issue again

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017` connects to the locally installed MongoDB without using credentials (by default MongoDB runs without authentication, which I consider as a major design fault). You need to provide your username and password.